# Webservice sending null in integer fields

Tags: .net, soap, soap-client

I am trying to use a 3rd party webservice.  One of the fields that is returned is defined as

```
<s:element name="SomeField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="s:int"/>
```

In the SOAP response they send the field as

```
<SomeField/>
```

This is causes the .Net deserializer to throw an exception as the empty xml element is not a valid integer.

What is the best way to handle this?

I have tried tweaking the wsdl to mark the field as nullable which does marked the generated fields as int?  but the deserializer still fails.

I can implement the endpoint as either a service reference or as a web service reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the .Net deserialiser can cope with this.

How about tweaking the definition of `SomeField` to a string.  This way can check for a null, but you would have to do an Int32.Parse to the real value.

```
<s:element name="SomeField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="s:string"/>
```

The accessor could be:

```
 void int? GetSomeField()
 {
     if (someField == null) return null;
     return In32.Parse(someField);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set the default to 0. That way if the value is not set it will send 0.

```
<s:element name="SomeField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="0" type="s:int"/>
```

Comment: I think this would work if I didn't need to handle nulls and 0 differently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in their code. That does not match the schema. XMLSpy says:

```
File Untitled6.xml is not valid.
Value '' is not allowed for element <SomeField>.
    Hint: A valid value would be '0'.
    Error location: root / SomeField
    Details
        cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: For type definition 'xs:int' the string '' does not match a literal in the lexical space of built-in type definition 'xs:int'.
        cvc-simple-type.1: For type definition 'xs:int' the string '' is not valid.
        cvc-type.3.1.3: The normalized value '' is not valid with respect to the type definition 'xs:int'.
        cvc-elt.5.2.1: The element <SomeField> is not valid with respect to the actual type definition 'xs:int'.
```

I got that with the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SomeField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:int"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Untitled5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SomeField/>
</root>
```

Comment: Agreed, but it is not my code to change so I need to work around it.

Comment: One of your responsibilities as the consumer of this data is to report bugs. This is a bug. Report it and then work around it - don't just work around it and not tell them about their bug. One of the reasons you're seeing this bug may be that nobody has reported it to them.

Comment: Yes all instances of this have been sent to the vendor.  Though it is their opinion that it is an issue with the Microsoft SOAP parser not with their output.  I have it working now.  If they fix their end it will make my side cleaner, and not break for any new developers if they get new WSDL from them.

Comment: Point this answer out to them: it's from XMLSpy, not from Microsoft.